# gcc Make sure that no c++ isms are compiled?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

If I use gcc as a driver, call all my source files .c and .h, can I be sure that I wont have any C++ source in my sources? Are there any gcc parameters to make sure that he throws errors in case any c++ is encountered in the source?

I am especially paranoid about include files, because I am not 100% sure whether I include C headers or C++ headers.

Some examples I ran into in the past:

- trying to use the type bool
- using wrong includes cstdio vs. stdio.h
- trouble with the struct keyword

I just want to make 100% sure that my source is only C and has no C++ in it.

Comment: Doesn't it do this by default when compiling a `.c` file?

Comment: You can use `gcc -x c` to force gcc to treat every file as C, though it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Type `bool` is valid if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`. Other than that, try adding a C++ construct and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think you can check portably if a C++ header was included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC will figure out itself whether it's a C or a C++ source code. How? It scans the file extension the file you passed has.
[These](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) are the extensions accepted.

In case you want to force a specific language, use the `-x` flag (documented in the link above). Furthermore, you may check whether the macro `__cplusplus` is defined.

Comment: I often see people using `.h` extension for C++ header files instead of e.g. `.hpp` or `hxx`. Simply scanning extension is not enough to disambiguate from C or C++ in this case. The executable used is a good hint though (i.e. gcc vs g++).

Comment: @Chnossos Yes, but headers cannot be compiled. That header will be included however in a C++ or a C source file.

Comment: Actually you can "compile" a header into a "[precompiled header](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html)".

Comment: True. But the languages need to match anyway.